# Keras Inception-V3 model predictions way off

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

So, I ran the Keras example code for using the inception-v3 model and the predictions are way off. I guess there is an error in the weights. Does someone know why is this happening.

I am using:
Keras 2.0.4, Python 3.5 (64 bit)

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py

This is the code I am running:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = InceptionV3(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')

    img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(299, 299))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    x = preprocess_input(x)

    preds = model.predict(x)
    print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds))
```

The result given is:

```
Predicted: [[('n01924916', 'flatworm', 0.99995065), ('n03047690', 'clog', 4.9389007e-05), ('n04366367', 'suspension_bridge', 1.075191e-08), ('n01665541', 'leatherback_turtle', 2.5111552e-10), ('n03950228', 'pitcher', 6.6290827e-11)]]
```

When I run the same image through the ResNet50 model, it gives out this results:

```
Predicted: [[('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.59942758), ('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.33637413), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant',
0.061940487), ('n02397096', 'warthog', 0.0016048651), ('n02396427', 'wild_boar', 0.00016479047)]]
```

### Edit

I tested other image on the inception-v3 model and it is giving the same predictions for every different image. Any insight on the problem will be apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Inception` and `ResNet` have different preprocessing function. In order to preprocess input for `Inception` try this function:

```
def preprocess_input(x):
    x /= 255.
    x -= 0.5
    x *= 2.
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `preprocess_input` from `xception` module

```
from keras.applications.xception import preprocess_input
```

or call `preprocess_input(images, mode='tf')`